# permission denied error on tomcat docker image deployment to openshift container - /usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml (permission denied)

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers, openshift, chown

Here is my `Dockerfile` content. When I run this locally it works well but when I try to deploy it on the `openshift container` it throws `permission denied` error

```
    FROM tomcat:8.0.36-jre8
    CMD groupadd -r myuser -g 501
    CMD useradd -d /home/myuser -u 501 -m -s /bin/bash -g myuser myuser
    CMD chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/tomcat
    ADD target/ui-1.0.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
    ADD docker-tomcat-conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
    ADD docker-tomcat-conf/web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
    ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

and the error

```
    Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.36-jre8
RUN groupadd -r myuser -g 501
RUN useradd -d /home/myuser -u 501 -m -s /bin/bash -g myuser myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/tomcat
ADD target/ui-1.0.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ADD docker-tomcat-conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ADD docker-tomcat-conf/web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

---

First of you need to replace the `CMD` commands with `RUN` statements.

Additionally, aren't you missing a `/` at

```
docker-tomcat-conf/web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF
```

I guess this should be

```
docker-tomcat-conf/web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/
```

or

```
docker-tomcat-conf/web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

---

Shouldn't `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/` be `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/`?

Answer (score 0):

There are might be some policies on the openshift site which not allow you to run your container in priviledged mode (e.g. use root account to run processes)

You must to find out under which user tomcat is started (see openshift policies, ask your cluster administrator)  and align all neccessary file and folder permissions accordingly, using chown and/or chmod in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

We will have to add permission to start tomcat with root.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

It should work.